# Clipping multiple AOIs from a lascatalog using a dataframe

Tags: clip, lidr

I'm tryin to clip multiple AOIs from a `Lascatalog` using a `dataframe` containing centres and radii of various plots.

I can probably loop through the data frame and use `lasclipCircle()` to clip each plot and write it. I was wondering if there is a more efficient way to simultaneously do this while retaining the plot ID (from the `dataframe`) for each file, if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation of `lasclipCircle()` states that you can input multiple coordinates (plural is used)

> `xcenter` numeric. x coordinates of discs centers.
>
> `ycenter` numeric. y coordinates of discs centers.
>
> `radius` numeric. disc radius or radii.

So it works as you may expect

```r
ctg = readLAScatalog(...)
p   = read.table(...)
aois = lasclipCircle(ctg, p$x, p$y, p$radius) # AOIs is a list of LAS
```

The output is a `list` of `LAS` object so you can rename it with you AOIs IDs if you want. And you automatically get access to all the feature of the `LAScatalog` processing engine so the following works to write your AOIs on files (see the documentation of the engine `?lidR::LAScatalog-class`)

```r
opt_filter(ctg) <- "-keep_first"
opt_output_file <- "/folder/AOI_{ID}"
aois = lasclipCircle(ctg, p$x, p$y, 10) # aois is a LAScatalog
```

You can also find a solution using `lasclip()` with a shapefile [here](https://github.com/Jean-Romain/lidR/wiki/Area-based-approach-from-A-to-Z) to preserve attributes with filenames. Something like that will work:

```r
coordinates(p) <- ~x+y # cast to SpatialPointsDataFrame
opt_filter(ctg) <- "-keep_first"
opt_output_file <- "/folder/AOI_{AOIID}" # If AOIID is the name of a column
aois = lasclip(ctg, p, radius = 10)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! The clipping worked well with all the methods
I have the following questions:
1) opt_output_file <- "/folder/AOI_{ID}" is only creating a variable with a value i.e. the string
2) I am not able to access the attribute entries for every shapefile. Instead, every clipped entity has the entire path along with the name of the column. Basically, the name is the same for all the entities.

Comment: Please ask a new question with more details and reproducible examples.