# Configuring lascatalog to clip and export using a shapefile

Tags: lidr

I used the following commands as mentioned in the answer [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/346795/clipping-multiple-aois-from-a-lascatalog-using-a-dataframe/346812?noredirect=1#comment567973_346812)

`ctg = readLAScatalog(...)
 p   = read.table(...)
 opt_output_file <- "/folder/AOI_{Id_placett}"
 aois = lasclipCircle(ctg, p$x, p$y, 10)`

The `opt_output_file <- "/folder/AOI_{Id_placett}"` command only created a  variable named 'opt_output_file'. Apparently, this variable was not used in the following clipping command and the results was a lascatalog named 'aois' only. No files were written.

I then used the ABA approach. [Here](https://github.com/Jean-Romain/lidR/wiki/Area-based-approach-from-A-to-Z) it seems to have been used differently, as follows:

```
ctg <- readLAScatalog(...)
plots <- st_read("...")
opt_output_files(ctg) <- paste0(tempdir(), "/{Id_placett}") #Id_placett is the column name
plots_ALS_clipped <- lasclip(ctg, plots, radius=15)
```

The lascatalog i.e. ctg is mentioned in the command `opt_output_files(ctg)`. This seems to have worked and a temporary folder was created. But there are two issues that I encountered:

1) If I replace `tempdir()` with another path, I don't see any files in the location specified by me. There are some files (not all clipped plots) in the RtmpSQSLrf folder shown below. In the [ABA](https://github.com/Jean-Romain/lidR/wiki/Area-based-approach-from-A-to-Z) example, it was mentioned that the clipped plots will be saved on the HDD

2) {/Id_placette} is used as a column name to retain the names of the clipping polygons. But all the clipped las entities in the lascatalog end with the column name i.e. "Id_placett". I thought they are supposed to end with corresponding clipping polygon names.

For example, `plots_ALS_clipped@data$filename` returns the following (showing only first few entries):

```
 [1] "\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\RtmpSQSLrf\\Id_placett.las"
 [2] "\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\RtmpSQSLrf\\Id_placett.las"
 [3] "\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\RtmpSQSLrf\\Id_placett.las"
 [4] "\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\RtmpSQSLrf\\Id_placett.las"
 [5] "\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\RtmpSQSLrf\\Id_placett.las"
```

As you can see, all the clipped areas in the plots_ALS_clipped are named as 'Id_placett'

Comment: Please edit your question to be more accurate. I do not understand if `p` is a `data.frame` or not. If `plots` is a `SpatialPointsDataFrame` of not. You didn't tell us the names of your columns neither in `p` nor in `plots`. Tell us more about your objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```r
opt_output_file(ctg) <- "/folder/AOI_{Id_placett}"
aois = lasclipCircle(ctg, p$x, p$y, 10)
```

The above mentioned code cannot work because `lasclipCircle()` has no way to know where to find `Id_placett`. `lasclipCircle` only support regular templates such as `XLEFT`, `YBOTTOM`, `ID`, `XCENTER` and so on.

```r
opt_output_files(ctg) <- paste0(tempdir(), "/{Id_placett}") #Id_placett is the column name
plots_ALS_clipped <- lasclip(ctg, plots, radius=15)
```

The above mentioned code is good. It is expected to work. A bug has been fixed in v2.2.0. Please update if not up-to-date. Maybe your trouble come from that. Anyway it indeed puts the output in `tempdir()`.

> `{Id_placett}` is used as a column name to retain the names of the clipping polygons. But all the clipped las entities in the `LAScatalog` end with the column name i.e. `Id_placett`

It should work. Update and if it still does not work please provide a reproducible example. And check twice if it is Id_placet, Id_placett or Id_placette. Your used each variation

Comment: The problem related to the path is solved. I am able to specify the location of the output. However, there is only one file named 'Id_placett.las' in the output folder. Seems like the other files which have the same name were overwritten. I used `opt_output_files(ctg) <- paste0(pth, "/{colnames(plots)[1]}")` to extract the column name from the shape file and join it to the path. Please let me know if this description is clear. Thanks!

Comment: Do not try to put something else than what is allowed. In your case `{Id_placett}`. It won't crash but it won't give you the expected result. If it does not work edit your question with a fully (minimal) reproducible code and summary of your objects. We cannot guess what you did wrong.

Comment: Following the method shown in the ABA example for lidR, when I use only `{Id_placett}`, I get the error `object 'Id_placett' not found`. In any case, I will try to provide a reproducible example!

Comment: Solved! There was a problem during the installation of the update. Fixed it and worked. Thanks for the help!